# enable read-only access to cookies in Javascript

Tags: javascript, http, cookies

Is it possible that you disable setting cookies in javascript while stil being able to read them? 
In my website i set cookies only in php, but it would be usefull that i can read them from Javascript.
I know there is a httpOnly flag while creating cookie but that restrict read and write access from Javascript.
The reason why i want to restrict write access is of course security as user can easily set cookie even from browser and i want to prevent that.

Comment: "*user can easily set cookie*" - he **always** can do that, no matter what your server tells him. Even for httpOnly cookies. Do not trust the client, every request is spoofable.

Comment: that is true, but i wanted to minimize risk. Anyway, it is not easy to implement "remember me" feature with session so i went to cookie. And that feature is requested. Any other suggestion? :)

Comment: You want to minize the risk of what? Suggestion: Just use the cookie.

Comment: The risk that user log to system as somebody else by changing cookie.

Comment: @BojanKovacevic - Please make sure you dont just store a username/password in a cookie (or even just a username). That is a huge security flaw. You should be storing a "key" which you can verify belongs to a valid user without giving away how you generate that key. That is what stops somebody "just changing the cookie to log in/spoof somebody else's account"

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is create two cookies:

MY_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY

MY_COOKIE

With the same values in the backend. One which is http only and the other which isn't. The MY_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY cookie will be used in the backend and MY_COOKIE will be used in the browser. If attacker changes the value of MY_COOKIE in the browser side, well that basically is ok since if attacker has access to your browser, they can do all sorts of things but only in the browser side.

And on the other hand, you will be able to identify this situation by comparing the values.

Answer (score 1):

Shortest answer: No. It's not possible.

Comment: Wouldn't the shortest answer just be "no"? :p

Comment: Ok. Thx for cheering me up :D

Comment: @Kolink - no, that would be the shortest answer if SO didnt enforce a minimum answer length, which it does.

Answer (score 0):

you can prevetn the browser from setting javascript cookies by **overriding** the setter of `document.cookie`

```
document.__defineGetter__("cookie", document.__lookupGetter__("cookie") );
document.__defineSetter__("cookie", function() {} );
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, you can't stop users from editing files on their own computers, which is effectively what you would need to do to stop them from editing a cookie.

That doesn't mean you're out of options though. You could include an authentication code (like [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC)) in the cookie. The user will still be able to read and change that cookie, but at least you will be able to detect when they do and ignore the provided data.